# Does BigQuery implement a swap for CREATE OR REPLACE?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery as part of a metric store and trying to figure out how it orchestrates replacing tables. Specifically, is submitting a job like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {table_path}
AS
{query}
```

implemented as a swap between a temp table and the original?

I looked at the query plan, but unfortunately it only shows intermediate results. Here's an example of plan output I see, with irrelevant parts omitted,

```
READ
{...}
COMPUTE
{...}
WRITE
[{...}, 'TO __stage00_output']
READ
['FROM __stage00_output']
READ
[{...}, 'FROM __stage01_output']
WRITE
[{...}, 'TO __stage02_output']
```

Can I assume that `__stage02_output` is being swapped in for  `{table_path}` at the end, or is something else going on?

Comment: maybe if you would explain more the context of why you ask this question, It would help people to answer your question.

Comment: Sure @HuiZheng. I was curious to learn what would happen to a read transaction while a CREATE OR REPLACE job was running.

As I understand it, [BigQuery uses MVCC](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery), and my guess is that means read transactions get the previous version of the db until the replace job has committed, but I couldn't find this specified anywhere.

Comment: The `CREATE or REPLACE` would be an atomic transaction. The read transactions would either get all data from the previous version or get all data from the new version. It won't get a mix of data from both versions if that's what you are concerned about.